# Is it possible to get a tracking changes in a Azure DevOps task, day by day?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to get, day by day, the changes that occurs in an Azure DevOps task, especially in the remaining work field. Example:

Date Change | Remaining Work | Title

08/05/2020  | 10             | Code and unit test

08/06/2020  |  5             | Code and unit test

08/07/2020  |  0             | Code complete and unit test passed

Can anyone provide some approach to get this info?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: Hi @Daniel! This information is to make a report in xls format, which has nothing to do with Scrum or new mindsets. There are legacy issues.

Comment: @Hernán That doesn't answer my question. You're providing a list of requirements; my question is asking what **you** have tried to do to implement your requirements.

Comment: @Daniel, I have tried using queries and the API but none of the options satisfy me. I am looking for some more direct approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get a tracking changes in a Azure DevOps task, day by day?

We can check the changed content by getting the content in the **work item history**.

I would like to sharing the following two methods:

Method1: You could use [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the Work item History.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/revisions?api-version=5.1
```

In the Rest API result, you could get the changed date and other work item settings(e.g. Remaining Work).

[image]

Method2: You could use `Analytics views` to create a view . Then you could use `PowerBI` to create a chart to show all information.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create a custom View in `Azure Devops -> Overview -> Analytics views`

You could set the required field , select work item id and History Scope (e.g. All History) in the View.

Step2: In PowerBI, select `Get Data -> Azure Devops -> Target View` to create a new chart.

[image]

Result:

[image]

For more detailed steps, you could refer to this doc about [Create an Analytics view in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-views-create?view=azure-devops) and [Applying filters to historical data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-historical-filtering?view=azure-devops)

**Update:**

The Work item filter of Analytics views.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kevin. Method 1 I knew about it, but I don't know if it can be applied in all tasks, regardless of the task ID

Comment: @Hernán. Yes. The Rest API could only return the history of single WorkItem. It has some limitations. But the method2  ( **Analytics views** ) supports to return the custom list of work item. You could directly get the  history of work items , regardless of the task ID. You could try method2 and check if it could meet your requirements.

Comment: Hi @Hernán. Is there any update about this ticket? Could you please check if the Analytics views could meet your requirements?Feel free to let me konw if you have any questions.