# Azure devops IAAS check repository completeness

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, iaas

We use pipelines/IAAS in Azure DevOps in order to setup our environments in Azure. Sometimes we notice inconsistency between what we have in the master/develop branch of our repo and what we see in the protal, meaning there have been changes which were done in the protal, but not in the repo. Somebody any ideas on how to track these inconsitencies in an automated way?
Thanks and regards,
Luc

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to track changes in the devops pipeline, then you can
  check the history tab itself which will give you history of all the
  pipeline.
- There are also other ways to finds the difference between the versions of pipeline such as using rest api and powerbi.
- For rest api it will give history of a specific work item and not the entire history.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/revisions?api-version=5.1
```

- Another way would be by using powerbi which will give the entire history and you can customize it too. It will be under analytics view tag in azure devops.

Refer this SO thread [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63293236/is-it-possible-to-get-a-tracking-changes-in-a-azure-devops-task-day-by-day) by Kevin Lu-MSFT